# How to update access keys and secret keys for Data transfer Config

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have setup a data transfer config between Big Query and Amazon S3, and Big Query data transfer service support connection with AWS using  AWS access keys and secret keys. Because of key rotation policy for AWS, secret keys and access keys are rotated after fixed interval of time. So how should we update the new access keys and secret keys for data transfer config by creating some script.